# Animated Listbox scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a vertical WPF listbox, bound to a collection, with a custom ItemTemplate. I've noticed a few things:

1. Unlike a standalone scrollviewer, the listbox does not scroll continuously, but jumps in increments equal to the height of the items. Where in XAML is this difference defined (the listbox template just contains a scrollviewer after all?
2. Is it possible to animate this jump? I'm trying to animate this so that it quickly animates the jump from one offset to another. Icing on the cake would be for the animation to display some interia and 'wobble' at the end. I was hoping there would be a pre defined Behavior for this, but there seems not to be one. Attempts at doing this myself in code behind with BeginAnimation have failed, with an Exception thrown telling me that the VerticalOffset property of Scrollviewer cannot be animated.

Any clues?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 5):

1- If you want scroll not to jump, you can change ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to False.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" .... >.....</ListBox>
```

2- You can create you own control that is able to animate it's offset.

MyScrollViewer Class

```
public class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MyScrollViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(onChanged)));

    public double MyOffset
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { this.ScrollToVerticalOffset(value); }
    }
    private static void onChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyScrollViewer)d).MyOffset = (double)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

in MainWindow.xaml or something

```
<Grid>
    <my:MyScrollViewer x:Name="myScroll">
        <ListBox x:Name="myList">

        </ListBox>
    </my:MyScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="Down"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="10"
                    Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
            myList.Items.Add(i);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double offset = (double)myScroll.GetValue(MyScrollViewer.MyOffsetProperty);
        DoubleAnimation goDown = new DoubleAnimation(
            offset,
            offset + 100,
            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
        myScroll.BeginAnimation(MyScrollViewer.MyOffsetProperty, goDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. That answers the first thing I asked, thanks! No, what I'd like is to keep the jump, but to animate it.

Comment: Using ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double) method, you can write your own animation/control.